# Node.js with Socket.io - Long Polling fails and throws “code”:1,“message”:“Session ID unknown” response

Tags: node.js

Please give solution-
All my socket polling requests are failing with the following error.

```
{"code":1,"message":"Session ID unknown"}
```

Comment: Are you using `ngnix`?

Comment: https://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LqtR6Rn&sid=0JFGcEFNdrS-XBZxHAXM`, this is the long poll call that client makes to the server, if you see here it is passing the sessionId, the node identifies the socket connection for which the request has been made and responds.

But in some cases, like dealing with multiple nodes/Amazon ELB the call may go to some other node that didn't generate this sessioIs, in that case the node will not be able to identify the sessionId for which the call was made and hence responds with {"code":1,"message":"Session ID unknown"}

You will also see this error in case of long polling not getting answered or getting timeout.

## Nginx

You will need `ip_hash` in upstream server definition and some headers.

[SocketIO NginX Configuration (Using Multiple Nodes)](https://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/#nginx-configuration)

## Amazon ELB

For those who are having this issue behind a amazon ELB, make sure you enable application-controlled [session stickiness](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html)